# How to Active Dynamic <li> or Video Tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api

I am retrieving videos from YouTube playlist and it loads into carousal.

Now, I want to Active dynamic < li >. When i click any of one < li > or Video (Which is inside into < li >. It suppose to be active.

```
var playListURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/'+nPlaylistID+'?v=2&alt=json&callback=?';
var videoURL= 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=';
$.getJSON(playListURL, function(data) {
    var list_data="";
    $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {
        var feedTitle = item.title.$t;
        var feedURL = item.link[1].href;
        var fragments = feedURL.split("/");
        var videoID = fragments[fragments.length - 2];
        var url = videoURL + videoID;
        var thumb = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+ videoID +"/default.jpg";
        list_data += '<li><a href= "#" title="'+ feedTitle +'" onClick=show_yt_vid("'+videoID+'");><img src="'+ thumb +'" /></a></li>';
    });
```

> Demo Link:- http://jsfiddle.net/4hHaG/
>
> Screen Shot (How I want) :-
>   https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1EUrqDt0LieWUEydnVIUTh6NWM/edit?usp=sharing

Thanx in Advance !!!!!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I suggest is: 
add a class to the a tags in the loop

```
        list_data += '<li><a class="vids" href= "#" title="'+ feedTitle +'" onClick=show_yt_vid("'+videoID+'");><img src="'+ thumb +'" /></a></li>';
```

and then use jquery to add a class to the element clicked

```
        $(document).on('click', '.vids', function() {
            $('.vids').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
```

here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4hHaG/1/
Just add a background to the class 'active' in the css with the image you want